# Angular datatable rerendering generate duplicates in table, duplicate gone in page refresh

Tags: angular, datatables, rerender

this is my data generating function for datatable(angular), at the initial run it trigger correctly and shows data in table, and the problem happened when updating a data, on update the table rerendered with duplicate rows when I refresh the page it showed correctly

```
generateSlotData(provider: any){
this.allSlotData = [];
let tempSlotData: any = [];
let groups: any = [];
let lanes: any = [];
let customers: any = [];
this.db.fetchAllData(provider).subscribe((res: any)=>{

  res.rows.forEach((element: any) => {
    this.tempSlotData.push(Object.assign({}, element.value));
  });

  this.db.fetchGroups(provider).subscribe((res: any) => {
    res.rows.forEach((element: any) => {
      groups.push(Object.assign({}, element.value));
      this.groupsData.push(Object.assign({}, element.value));
    });
    this.tempSlotData.forEach((slot: any) => {
      const temp = this.groupsData.find((group: any) => group._id === slot.group_id);
      if(temp){
        slot.group_name = temp.name;
      } else {
        slot.group_name = 'Default Group';
      }
    });

    this.db.fetchLanes(provider).subscribe((res: any) => {
      res.rows.forEach((element: any) => {
        lanes.push(Object.assign({}, element.value));
        this.lanesData.push(Object.assign({}, element.value));
      });
      this.tempSlotData.forEach((slot: any) => {
        const temp = this.lanesData.find((lane: any) => lane._id === slot.lane_id);
        if(temp){
          slot.lane_name = temp.name;
        } else {
          slot.lane_name = 'Default Lane';
        }
      });  

      this.db.fetchCustomers(this.provider).subscribe((res: any)=>{
        res.rows.forEach((element: any) => {
          customers.push(Object.assign({}, element.value));
          this.customersData.push(Object.assign({}, element.value));
        });
        this.tempSlotData.forEach((slot: any) => {
          const temp = this.customersData.find((customer: any) => customer.customerid === slot.user_id);
          if(temp){
            slot.user_name = temp.fname + ' ' + temp.lname;
            slot.user_phone = temp.phone;
            slot.user_email = temp.email;
          }
        });

        this.tempSlotData.forEach((slot: any) => {
          const d = new Date(slot.date);
          const day = d.toISOString().split('T')[0];
          const data = {
            slot_id: slot._id,
            rev: slot._rev,
            date: day,
            token: slot.token_number,
            fullname: slot.user_name,
            phone: slot.user_phone,
            email: slot.user_email,
            time: slot.slot,
            lane: slot.lane_name,
            lane_id: slot.lane_id,
            group: slot.group_name,
            group_id: slot.group_id,
            status: slot.booking_status,
            additional_details: slot.additional_details
          };
          this.allSlotData.push(data);
        });
        if (this.isDtInitialized) {
          this.dtElement.dtInstance.then((dtInstance: DataTables.Api) => {
              dtInstance.destroy();
              this.dtTrigger.next(this.allSlotData);
          });
        } else {
            this.isDtInitialized = true;
            this.dtTrigger.next(this.allSlotData);
        }
      });
    });
  });
});
```

}

after an update i am calling the same function to rerender the table, but the result is if there is 4 rows when generated first after update the rows are duplicated multiple times, i am adding screenshots of both,

[image: datable table before update]

[image: datatable after update]

Comment: Maybe you should tell us what does "fetchAllData" do

Comment: fetchAllData just get slot documents only @nicolascolman

Comment: did you try doing console.log of tempSlotData within the subscribe callback?